# How to use variable from another method in a WinForms C# Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm attempting to create a simple WinForms application written in C# that:

1. Takes user input from a text box.
2. Uses the data from that text box, and stores it in a `user_command` variable, which is then used in a method that runs the string in that variable in windows cmd.

E.g: I enter "calc.exe" in the text box. The program then passes that into cmd, therefore opening the calculator.

I am unaware of how I use that data from that text-box and put it into `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", user_command);`

I will leave all the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace gui_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user_command = textBox1.Text;

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, string user_command)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", user_command);
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
Error   CS0123  No overload for 'textBox1_TextChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler'  gui_1
```

Comment: Your application logic does not make sense: You read the text of the text box when the button is clicked, but you start a program (based on the old text box content in the variable) when the text changes. Wouldn't it be easier (and more correct) to do all this when the button is clicked?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm pretty sure I put it in the wrong method. I should have, as you said, put that into the 'button1_click' method. Thank you so much for helping me realize such a stupid mistake

Comment: In cases like that, you can define `user_command` as a global parameter (choose access modifier by your needs...) and then use it on methods.

Comment: Variables declared in methods are called "local variables" and their visibility scope is limited to the method body or to a nested code block within it (e.g. an if-block) where this variable is declared. To share it between several methods, declare it as a class field, i.e., outside of any method declaration, which extends its visibility to the whole class.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is you put a third parameters on your textBox1_TextChange eventhandler which causing you the error.

I suggest you put the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", user_command);` on to the button1_Click event, and remove the 3rd parameter on your textBox1_TextChange.
When you click the button1 it will run the `CMD.exe` with the `user_command` as argument.

```
namespace gui_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user_command = textBox1.Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", user_command);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

executing different process with arguments.
try to type on your `textbox1` before clicking the button1 `c:\test.txt`.

this will try to open test.txt file on your drive c: on the notepad and ask you if you want to create the file if it is not existing.

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user_command = textBox1.Text;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", user_command);
    }
```

EDIT2:

executing `CMD.exe` to execute the parameter.

`/c` argument will execute the arguments entered on textbox1 upon starting the CMD.exe

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user_command = textBox1.Text;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c " + user_command);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that, but once I run the program, enter a command into the text box, and click "Submit", it opens an empty cmd terminal.  So I have a feeling it's still not grabbing the text from the text box for some reason.

Comment: @cx1_0: (1) To verify that you are grabbing the text correctly, just [put a break point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022) in your code and read the contents of user_command. (2) cmd is not starting your command because you need to use either the /c or the /k command-line switch, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Comment: @cx1_0, It is grabbing the text from the textbox, the problem is you are executing the cmd.exe with an argument, which will only open empty terminal with or without the arguments. If you are executing another program, just use the specific program on the process.start to execute it.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a string into cmd through C#, though? I have debugged and you're right, it is grabbing the text.

Comment: If you are trying to execute something on the cmd, I suggest you execute a batch file instead.

Comment: @Henry: I have taken the liberty to add a space between `/c` and the command in your answer.

Comment: @Henry I tried that out and it seems to work. Thank You. Is there a way to keep the CMD open, so it doesn't close instantly?

Comment: @cx1_0: To keep the command window open, use `/k` instead of `/c`. Again, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Answer (score 0):

The eventargs (e) should contain the value in the checkbox. put a breakpoint and inspect it. I am sure you will find the text in there.

Remove your third parameter to start matching the overload again !

I hope this code is for educational purposes since it will open a huge gap in the security of the server it is running on.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm a fairly new C# Developer and have only just recently wrapped my head around the methods used in a C# Application. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: I think the other answers are pointing you in the right direction. I think it is now just a question of getting the CMD to execute. (that has nothing to do with the origunal question btw) because @STG anwered the original question in the comments already